# onDelete cascade not deleting child

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have the following class and relationship:

```
/**
 * App\MainBundle\Entity\PictureRenamer
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_picture_renamer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\MainBundle\Repository\PictureRenamerRepository")
 */
class PictureRenamer
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="itemrenamer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="renamer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $renamer;

}


class InstagramShopPicture
{
     /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

      /**
     * @Exclude()   
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\MainBundle\Entity\PictureRenamer", mappedBy="picture", cascade={"persist","remove"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    protected $renamer;

}
```

however why is it that when I call `$em->remove($picture);` then I flush it, it doesn't remove the picture renamer? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is the delete cascade set on the foreign key in the database?
When setting the cascade on the `JoinColumn` the database should manage the cascade.

Try adding `, cascade={"remove"}` to the `ManyToOne` instead of the `JoinColumn`. This way Doctrine will manage the cascade itself.